# How can I reapply a texture to the new modified mesh after using the bevel modifier in 3DS Max?

Tags: 3d, 3ds-max

See the screenshot attached.

The rainbow texture was applied to a very thin half-circle as you can see.
After bevelling, I was able to make the semi-circle wider as intended but the texture "has not followed" : it is not covering the whole surface.

How can I make it cover the whole surface ? I thought about somehow merging faces so the texture would apply to the whole surface but I have no idea how that would work or if it would have the intended effect.

What are your suggestions ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the Bevel tool again worked this time. The texture correctly re-applied itself to the new surface. Don't know why it didn't work the first time.